# How to increase speed of stored procedure when using order by statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, pagination, sql-order-by

I have a stored procedure that returns almost 16000 rows. It also has pagination and returns 10 rows on each page.

This procedure returns user's tickets; when I use `order by` for sorting them, its execution speed slows down. I checked the execution plan but I don't get useful information, and just I got that `order by` has warning that operator used tempdb to spill data during execution with spill level 1 and 1 spilled threads, but I don't know how can I solve it.

I would like to know, how can I make my procedure execution faster?

This is my procedure:

```
    ;WITH Tickets AS 
    (
        SELECT
            t.Id ,
            t.[Subject] ,
            t.UserId,
            t.PriorityId,
            u.UserName,
            c.[Name] AS UserCompanyName,
            t.[Description],
            t.LastStatus AS StatusId,
            s.[Name] AS [Status],
            t.Number AS TicketNumber,
            t.CreateOn,
            t.CompanyProjectId AS ProjectId ,
            (SELECT TOP 1 [Name] FROM CompanyProject 
             WHERE CrmProjectId = t.CompanyProjectId) AS ProjectName , 
            t.[TempNumber],
            t.TypeRequestId AS RequestTypeId,
            rt.[Name] AS RequestTypeName,
            psc.NewMessagesCount,
            FORMAT(DATEADD(MINUTE, t.FirstResponsePace, t.CreateOn), 'yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm', 'fa') AS FirstResponsePace,
            FORMAT(DATEADD(MINUTE, t.FinishedPace, t.CreateOn), 'yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm', 'fa') AS FinishedPace,
            CASE
                WHEN t.SlaType IS NULL THEN N'تعیین نشده'
                WHEN t.SlaType = '' THEN N'تعیین نشده'
                ELSE t.SlaType
            END AS SlaType
        FROM
            Ticket t
        LEFT OUTER JOIN 
            dbo.AspNetUsers u ON t.UserId = u.Id
        INNER JOIN 
            #TempSubUsers tree ON tree.UserId = u.Id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN 
            dbo.AssignmentPosition ap ON u.Id = ap.UserId
        LEFT OUTER JOIN 
            dbo.Company c ON c.id = ap.CompanyId
        LEFT OUTER JOIN 
            dbo.RequestType rt ON rt.Id = t.TypeRequestId
        LEFT OUTER JOIN 
            dbo.[Status] s ON s.Id = t.LastStatus
        OUTER APPLY 
            (SELECT COUNT(1) AS NewMessagesCount 
             FROM dbo.ProcessStepComment
             WHERE EntityId = t.Id AND Seen = 0 AND UserId IS NULL
             GROUP BY EntityId) psc
        WHERE
            (t.Id = @id OR ISNULL(@id, CAST(0x0 AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER)) = CAST(0x0 AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER))
            AND (t.CreateOn >= @sdate OR ISNULL(@sdate, '') = '')
            AND (t.CreateOn <= @edate OR ISNULL(@edate, '') = '')
            AND ((t.[Subject] LIKE N'%' + @generalSearch + N'%' 
                  OR t.Number LIKE N'%' + @generalSearch + N'%' 
                  OR t.TempNumber LIKE N'%' + @generalSearch + N'%') 
                 OR ISNULL(@generalSearch, '') = '') 
            AND (t.LastStatus IN (@allStatusIdListString) 
                 OR (SELECT COALESCE(@allStatusIdListString, CAST(0x0 AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER))) = CAST(0x0 AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER))
            AND (t.TypeRequestId = @requestTypeId OR 
                 ISNULL(@requestTypeId, @UniqueIdentifierDefault) = @UniqueIdentifierDefault)
            AND (t.UserId = @userId OR ISNULL(@userId, '') = '')
            AND (t.CompanyProjectId = @companyProject 
                 OR ISNULL(@companyProject, @UniqueIdentifierDefault) = @UniqueIdentifierDefault)
            AND (c.Id = @companyId OR ISNULL(@companyId, @UniqueIdentifierDefault) = @UniqueIdentifierDefault)
            AND t.[IsEnable] = 1
    )
    SELECT * 
    FROM Tickets
    ORDER BY 
        NewMessagesCount DESC,
        CASE StatusId 
            WHEN 'A4E6D31F-ECD1-4288-863F-D4D5449C19D3' THEN 1
            WHEN 'EB1566A1-35FD-4C8F-AC27-DB7B02D68299' THEN 2
            WHEN '14F7090A-412B-4467-966F-CFEA59F7C434' THEN 3  
            WHEN 'E9FFB96F-2770-4763-A58D-E363D0903FB4' THEN 4  
            WHEN 'D002E7AA-2599-4B3C-89E6-DE8A74023E6A' THEN 5  
            WHEN '1A20087B-D8F1-437F-BC60-4723E5AFEB1A' THEN 6  
            WHEN '04BE6210-CBF9-4158-A464-7973F4FFDD6F' THEN 7  
            WHEN 'DF0F6E06-2AEC-4731-86DC-DF25981B852E' THEN 8  
            WHEN '5635F7AA-37DF-4EFF-B0C7-24E0C3BF4564' THEN 9  
            ELSE 10 
        END ASC,
        CreateOn DESC
OFFSET @PageSize * (@PageNumber - 1) rows fetch next @PageSize rows ONLY
```

Comment: Are the joining and order by columns all correctly indexed?

Comment: The semicolon is a statement **terminator**, not a "beginator". Use them consistently and you don't need this lazy kludge of putting it in front of "with". FORMAT is a costly function - formatting belongs in your front-end. Using TOP without an ORDER BY clause is a logic fault and highly suspicious. Many left joins are logically inner joins due to your WHERE clause. As for the rest, you look at the execution plan.

Comment: @Kendle first column as NewMessagesCount can't be indexed

Comment: I suspect the problem is more the "catch-all" `WHERE` and you have a poorly cached plan. It really needs a `RECOMPILE` in th `OPTION` CLAUSE.

Comment: Also I'd get rid of all those `ISNULL(@Variable,'') = ''` and just do `@Variable IS NULL`

Comment: @Larnu I used OPTION(RECOMPILE), it was good at first but it make procedure slow after a while

Comment: With so many various and varied search arguments this would really benefit from being built dynamically.

Comment: For performance questions, we really need to see the table *and index* definitions, and please share the query plan via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan

Comment: To get rid of the spill, knowing that the amount of rows coming back is going to be large but the estimate is not reflecting that, you can add `OPTION (MIN_GRANT_PERCENT = 5)` or some decent percentage of your Server Memory. That won't fix the numerous other problems with the query, but it will sort out your primary issue of the spill

Comment: @SMor Until statement terminators are mandatory, you’re going to have to get over it.

Comment: *"but it make procedure slow after a while"* `RECOMPILE` wouldn't do that, a poorly designed/indexed database or query would do that. `RECOMPILE` forces that data engine to recreate the query plan for the query, rather than using a cached one. It wouldn't cause the query to slow down unless the data engine is struggling to create a (good) query plan for the query; which would be due to poor indexing or out of date statistics. And if that's the case, then the problem isn't `RECOMPILE`.

Comment: you mention paging 10 rows at a time, are you expecting a user to navigate 1,600 pages? If not, tighten up your requirements and return less rows

Comment: `order by CreateDate` is working with a computed column from the CTE. You might have more success if you instead expose and order on the original `Ticket.CreateOn` column (and it is indexed). Really, presentation formatting is a task best dealt with in the presentation/application layer.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning you're right. I did it but I forgot edit the code. thanks

Comment: @maryam please create index like non cluster index which column u get in sorted and filtering from query its goes result getting faster way also improve  "SELECT COUNT(*) AS NewMessagesCount 
             FROM dbo.ProcessStepComment
             WHERE EntityId = t.Id AND Seen = 0 AND UserId IS NULL
             GROUP BY EntityId"
Why u used that instead of this
SELECT COUNT(1) AS NewMessagesCount 
             FROM dbo.ProcessStepComment
             WHERE EntityId = t.Id AND Seen = 0 AND UserId IS NULL
             GROUP BY EntityId
because query grouping with so much time..

Comment: @DOTNETTeam-WeblineIndia Thanks, I changed all "SELECT COUNT(*)" to "SELECT COUNT(1)"

Comment: I don't know It is good that make "CASE StatusId ... " as a new column and then set order on this column.

Comment: `COUNT(*)` and `COUNT(1)` are identical, there is no reason one would ever be slower or faster than the other.